# Webpack file-loader ONLY outputs PNG files

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

I'm currently attempting to merge an existing project to webpack 2. One of the things I'm currently struggling with is the file-loader. Normally you'd expect that it grabs all image files from `<img>` and `background-image` sources, and then place them in your dist folder.

This is currently in my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
entry: {
    main: './main.js'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: "/dist",
    filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
         //...
        {
           test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
           use: [{
              loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=/images/'
            }]
        },
        //...
        ]
     }
};
```

After running the webpack command, My dist folder has an images folder, and it **only** contains the PNG files. All other files are being ignored for some reason.

I'm struggling with it a couple of days now, and I can't find a logical explanation why this happens.

Comment: How are you referencing the images?

Comment: @BrandonPugh What do you mean? I'm using <img> tags in my html and background-image in my (s)css files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that webpack only picks up images from stylesheets through `@import` and `url()` and in javascript when you require an image like `const src = require('./logo.jpg');`.
So it wouldn't pick up any images that were just referenced in html files which in your case just happened to be the jpegs.

The [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) might be what you need to have those images also copied to dist.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.